# Geopandas Fast Read Slice of GeoPackage Format

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to chunk over a geopandas dataframe in order to limit peak memory. Unfortunately [geopandas.read_file](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html) doesn't have a `chunksize` option like [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) does.

Therefore I've been using the `rows=slice(start, end)` option of `read_file` in a `while` loop incrementing `start` and `end` until I run out of rows. The rub is that it looks like it re-reads the whole file with each call:

```
In [1]: import geopandas as gpd

In [2]: fulldata = gpd.read_file('data.gpkg')

In [3]: len(fulldata)
Out[3]: 127433

In [4]: %timeit gpd.read_file('data.gpkg', rows=slice(0, 100))
52 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit gpd.read_file('data.gpkg', rows=slice(127333, 127433))
1.14 s ± 17.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Reading 100 rows at the end of the file takes 21+ times longer than the beginning. As I chunk through the file I am spending most of my time re-reading parts of the file over and over. In `pandas.read_csv` the `chunksize` option works by keeping the file pointer open and stepping through the file in order.

Is there a way to chunk through a `gpkg` file in geopandas that efficient?

Answer (score 1):

This function may help you. It still loads all rows into memory, but it allows you to specify which fields you want to include, and fewer fields might sufficiently reduce memory load.

Importantly, the slices consistently load much faster than the entire file. Using perf_counter() each slice took ~0.18s to load while the entire file, loaded the normal way, took 7.13s to load.

```
def load2gdf_slices(in_fc, use_fields=None, chunk_size=1000):
i = 0
out_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
f_geom = 'geometry'

#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
while True:
    chunk = slice(i, i + chunk_size, 1)
    gdf_iter = gpd.read_file(in_fc, rows=chunk)

    if gdf_iter.shape[0] == 0:
        break
    else:
        if use_fields:
            if f_geom not in use_fields:
                use_fields.append('geometry')
            gdf_iter = gdf_iter[use_fields]

        out_gdf = out_gdf.append(gdf_iter)
        
        i += chunk_size
        

return out_gdf
```